# Write to Dead Letter Topic in case on Deserialization Exception

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I have a Spring Boot application that has a simple Consumer with @KafkaListener. I have blocking retry logic in place that works as expected but in case of Deserialization exception I want to store the corrupt message in DLT Topic to analyze and process manually later.

I am using DefaultErrorHandler and in case of Deserialization exception my code comes into this block without any retry attempts , which is the expected behaviour. But, problem lies with the **consumerRecord** param in my errorHandler. I do not get the message inside consumerRecord and hence message is saved as null in DLT . I want to somehow preserve the corrupt message and publish it to DLT.

```
DefaultErrorHandler errorHandler = new DefaultErrorHandler((consumerRecord, exception) -> {
        alerter.alert(exception,"Message Consumption Failed : " + consumerRecord.value() + " , sent to dead letter topic .");
        publisherService.sendMessageToDlq(DLQ_TOPIC, consumerRecord.value());}, fixedBackOff);
```

**consumerRecord.value()** is null :(

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the `ErrorHandlingDeserializer`, see the logic in the framework's `DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer` for how it gets the `DeserializationException` from the header (which has the raw data as a property).

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/blob/54601b1e829a3e9697b4933557a9d6bb16a7de7d/spring-kafka/src/main/java/org/springframework/kafka/listener/DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer.java#L474-L481